# Convert QBasic command to Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am creating a form using Adobe Acrobat Pro and I have to use a custom Calculation Script in a field.

In Qbasic it would be

```
If Qty > 1
Than TotPrice = Qty * UnitPrice
Else Totprice = ""
End if
```

In Exel it would be

```
If (Qty > 0, Qty*UnitPrice,"")
```

what would it be in JAVASCRIPT?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**It's better to read some online tutorials, or books**

Anyway Use something like below will solve your problem

```
 if(Qty> 1)
    {
    var TotPrice = Qty * UnitPrice;
    }
    else
    { 
    Totprice = "";
    }
```